# Инпут с датой записывается в state как undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

При выборе даты, значение в state не записывается.Проблема в handleChange как его переписать? Компонент в отдельном файле

Вот сам компонент

```js
class LocalizedUtils extends DateFnsUtils {
    getDatePickerHeaderText(date) {
        return format(date, "d MMM yyyy", {locale: this.locale});
    }
}

function DateFnsLocalizationExample() {
    const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState(new Date());

    return (
        <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={LocalizedUtils} locale={ruLocale}>
            <div className="md-form">
                <div className="d-flex">
                <MDBIcon far className="icon" icon="calendar-alt" />
                <DatePicker
                    clearable
                    helperText="Дата вашего приема"
                    value={selectedDate}
                    onChange={handleDateChange}
                    clearLabel="очистить"
                    cancelLabel="Отмена"
                    minDate={new Date("2019-04-01")}
                    maxDate={new Date("2019-06-01")}
                />
                </div>
            </div>
        </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
    );
}

export default DateFnsLocalizationExample;
```

```js
import React from "react";
import {Field, reduxForm} from "redux-form";
import {MDBCol, MDBContainer, MDBIcon, MDBInput, MDBRow} from "mdbreact";
import DatePick from "./DatePicker/TimePicker";
import {validate} from "./validation";
import InputMask from "react-input-mask";
import MaterialInput from "@material-ui/core/Input";
import axios from "axios";

const warn = values => {
    const warnings = {};
    if (values.age < 19) {
        warnings.age = "Hmm, you seem a bit young...";
    }
    if (!values.complaints) {
        warnings.complaints =
            "Желательно заполнить ваши жалобу, можно максимально кратко, чтоб доктору знать с чем он бдует иметь дело";
    }
    if (!/^[а-яё]+$/i.test(values.username)) {
        warnings.username = "Указывайте пожалуйста на русском ваши данные";
    }
    return warnings;
};
const renderMask = ({
                        input,
                        icon,
                        label,
                        id,
                        type,
                        meta: {touched, error, warning}
                    }) => (
    <div>
        <div className="d-flex">
            <MDBIcon icon="phone" className="icon"/>
            <InputMask mask="+375 (99) 999-99-99" disabled={false} {...input}>
                {inputProps => (
                    <MaterialInput
                        name="mobile"
                        {...inputProps}
                        type="tel"
                        fullWidth
                        disableUnderline
                        placeholder="Ваш номер телефона"
                    />
                )}
            </InputMask>
            {touched &&
            ((error && (
                    <span className="error_message">{`Поле ${label} ${error}`}</span>
                )) ||
                (warning && <span className="warning-color">{warning}</span>))}
        </div>
    </div>
);
const renderField = ({
                         input,
                         icon,
                         label,
                         id,
                         type,
                         meta: {touched, error, warning}
                     }) => (
    <div>
        <div>
            <MDBInput
                {...input}
                id={id}
                label={label}
                type={type}
                className="form-control"
                icon={icon}
            />
            {touched &&
            ((error && (
                    <span className="error_message">{`Поле ${label} ${error}`}</span>
                )) ||
                (warning && <span className="warning-color">{warning}</span>))}
        </div>
    </div>
);

class ValidationForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            username: "",
            lastname: "",
            date: "",
            email: "",
            mobile: "",
            age: "",
            complaints: "",
            doctor: ""
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.Submit = this.Submit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange = e => {
        this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
    };

    async Submit() {
        const {
            username,
            lastname,
            date,
            email,
            mobile,
            age,
            complaints,
            doctor
        } = this.state;

        const form1 = await axios.post("/api/patient", {
            username,
            lastname,
            date,
            email,
            mobile,
            age,
            complaints,
            doctor
        });

    }

    render() {
        const {handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting} = this.props;
        return (
            <MDBContainer>
                <MDBRow className="flex-center">
                    <MDBCol md="6">
                        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.Submit)} className="md-form">
                          Change={this.handleChange}
                            <Field
                                name="date"
                                icon="user"
                                type="text"
                                id="form3"
                                component={DatePick}
                                onChange={this.handleChange}
                            />
                            <div>
                                <button type="submit" disabled={submitting} className="btn btn-primary">
                                    Отправить ваши данные
                                </button>
                                <button
                                    type="button"
                                    disabled={pristine || submitting}
                                    onClick={reset}
                                >
                                    Clear Values
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </MDBCol>
                </MDBRow>
            </MDBContainer>

        )
    }
}

export default reduxForm({
    form: "ValidationForm", // a unique identifier for this form
    validate, // <--- validation function given to redux-form
    warn // <--- warning function given to redux-form
})(ValidationForm);
```

Comment: Поправьте приведённый код, т.к. он не выполняется.

Answer (score 0):

```
<DatePicker
  clearable
  helperText="Дата вашего приема"
  value={selectedDate}
  onChange={event => handleDateChange(event.value)}
  clearLabel="очистить"
  cancelLabel="Отмена"
  minDate={new Date("2019-04-01")}
  maxDate={new Date("2019-06-01")}
/>
```